# Interaction term failing lmerTest with In pf(F.stat, qr(Lc)$rank, nu.F) : NaNs produced

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to carry out an lmerTest on two separate datasets, and for some reason I am getting the following error for one of the datasets.

> In pf(F.stat, qr(Lc)$rank, nu.F) : NaNs produced

[This dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9jz9CiotnoER1dzUzRrVllVcm8/view?usp=sharing) gives me the p-value of the interaction term between `habitat` and `soil` without issue.

> anova(lmer(sqrt(abs) ~ habitat*soil + (1|species), data=frl_light,
>   REML=T))

```
Analysis of Variance Table of type III  with  Satterthwaite 
approximation for degrees of freedom
               Sum Sq  Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F.value  Pr(>F)  
habitat      0.057617 0.028809     2 8.8434  1.0880 0.37805  
soil         0.232708 0.232708     1 2.6732  8.7888 0.06848 .
habitat:soil 0.308003 0.154001     2 2.7134  5.8163 0.10443  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

[This dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9jz9CiotnoEdWkzbGhHM0RSVnM/view?usp=sharing) which has a similar structure however throws the error, and fails to give the p-value for the interaction between `habitat` and `light`. The density degree of freedom measurement is also 0, which is probably the problem.

> anova(lmer(sqrt(abs) ~ habitat*light + (1|species), data=frl_soil,
>   REML=T))

```
Analysis of Variance Table of type III  with  Satterthwaite 
approximation for degrees of freedom
               Sum Sq  Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F.value Pr(>F)
habitat       0.00845 0.004223     2 7.9751  0.3494 0.7154
light         0.01634 0.016336     1 1.9241  1.3517 0.3689
habitat:light 0.42813 0.214067     2 0.0000 17.7124       
Warning message:
In pf(F.stat, qr(Lc)$rank, nu.F) : NaNs produced
```

I have no idea why lmerTest works for one dataset but not the other as both datasets appear to me at least, to be virtually indistinguishable from one another. If there is anyone who can shed light on the matter, please help.

Update 1: I have tried Ben Bolker's suggestion to use the Kenward-Roger estimation instead. However, our answers seem to be differing. I am running R 3.3.1, lme4 1.1-12 and lmerTest 2.0-32. This is my output

> anova(lmer(sqrt(abs) ~ habitat*light + (1|species),
>   + data = frl_soil, REML = T),
>   + ddf="Kenward-Roger")

```
anova from lme4 is returned
some computational error has occurred in lmerTest
Analysis of Variance Table
              Df  Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value
habitat        2 0.00244 0.001219  0.1009
light          1 0.00476 0.004763  0.3941
habitat:light  2 0.42813 0.214067 17.7124
```

Update 1.1: Here's the output of the mixed-model analysis with SAS, where I added an additional column with the square-root of abs, as sqrtabs.

> FILENAME REFFILE '/folders/myfolders/frl_soil.csv';
>
> PROC IMPORT DATAFILE=REFFILE  DBMS=CSV    OUT=WORK.FRLSOIL;
>     GETNAMES=YES; RUN;
>
> PROC CONTENTS DATA=WORK.FRLSOIL; RUN;
>
> %web_open_table(WORK.FRLSOIL);
>
> PROC MIXED data = WORK.FRLSOIL;
>   CLASS species habitat light sqrtabs;
>   model sqrtabs = habitat light habitat*light / DDFM=KENWARDROGER;
>   random intercept species;
>   run;

```
Type 3 Tests of Fixed Effects
Effect         Num DF   Den DF  F Value     Pr > F
habitat             2       10     1.11     0.3681
light               1       10     0.45     0.5159
habitat*light       2       10     0.27     0.7716
```

Comment: The SAS differences are really quite mysterious. At the very least, the F-statistic for the interaction should be the same, regardless of the algorithm for deciding on denominator DF, contrasts, etc etc. ... are you sure you're using the same data set and the same transformation (sqrt) ... ???

Comment: Yes. Just to be sure I hadn't messed up, I downloaded the file I provided here, and re-ran the analysis with SAS just now. I will edit my comments with the SAS code.

Comment: Did you mean to have the `sqrtabs` included in your `CLASS` statement? I'm not sure what that would do ...

Comment: I did a square-root of the `abs` value then used those values in the model fitting in SAS. I am not too well-versed in SAS data manipulation so I created that column outside of SAS for the functional equivalent of `sqrt(abs)` in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't tell you exactly why the Satterthwaite approximation gives you a zero-df estimate here (which is indeed why you get the error and no $p$-value for the interaction); you'd have to work through the code in detail to see (type `lmerTest:::calcSatterthMultDF` and start digging ...) I did a *little* bit of digging; the key lines therein are

```
E <- sum((nu.m/(nu.m - 2)) * as.numeric(nu.m > 2))
nu.F <- 2 * E * as.numeric(E > q)/(E - q)
```

where (I think) `nu.m` ($\nu_m$) is the number of degrees of freedom as estimated by the [Welch-Satterthwaite approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%E2%80%93Satterthwaite_equation). I don't know why (1) `lmerTest` sets `E` and hence `nu.F` to zero when `nu.m <= 2`; (2) the particular combination of within-group variances in one data set gives `nu.m < 2` and in the other data set doesn't ...

In the meantime, though, you can use the Kenward-Roger approximation if you like (it's computationally more expensive, but in general slightly more accurate ...)  Using the data set from the second link:

```
frl_soil <- read.csv("frl_soil.csv")
library(lmerTest)
head(frl_soil,2)
##   X species habitat light        abs
## 1 1  ANI2GR     gen  G.cs 2.67477395
## 2 2  DIPTAC     gen  G.cs 0.09549154
anova(lmer(sqrt(abs) ~ habitat*light + (1|species), 
            data=frl_soil, REML=TRUE), 
     ddf="Kenward-Roger")
## Analysis of Variance Table of type III  with  Kenward-Roger 
## approximation for degrees of freedom
##                Sum Sq  Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F.value  Pr(>F)  
## habitat       0.00842 0.004208     2 8.1220  0.3482 0.71602  
## light         0.01568 0.015679     1 2.0712  1.2973 0.36928  
## habitat:light 0.40886 0.204432     2 2.0713 16.9152 0.05212 .
sessionInfo()
## other attached packages:
## [1] lmerTest_2.0-32 lme4_1.1-13     Matrix_1.2-6
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. However, I am not getting the same results from the dataset I provided you with Kenward-Roger. Running `anova(as(m1, "merModLmerTest"), ddf = "Kenward-Roger")` does not give me any p-values, and the F-values also differ substantially. Did you do any transformation to the dataset provided?

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to help me with this analysis. I have updated my question with further details of the lmerTest error that is being thrown out. Meanwhile, I have tried the same analysis with SAS which gives very different values from the R analysis you managed to run, namely the p-value for the interaction term is 0.77. This result has honestly stumped me and others in my lab.